# adding a field to each element of a list

Tags: r, list

I have a list

```
> (mylist <- list(list(a=1),list(a=2),list(a=3)))
[[1]]
[[1]]$a
[1] 1


[[2]]
[[2]]$a
[1] 2


[[3]]
[[3]]$a
[1] 3
```

and I want to add field `b` to each sublist from `11:13` to get something like

```
> (mylist <- list(list(a=1,b=11),list(a=2,b=12),list(a=3,b=13)))
[[1]]
[[1]]$a
[1] 1

[[1]]$b
[1] 11


[[2]]
[[2]]$a
[1] 2

[[2]]$b
[1] 12


[[3]]
[[3]]$a
[1] 3

[[3]]$b
[1] 13
```

How do I do this?

(note that I have a large number of such relatively small lists, so this will be called in `apply` and has to be reasonably fast).

Comment: `lapply(mylist, function(l) {l$b <- l$a+10; l})` should work, so long as you're actually adding 10 to each `a` value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mylist <- list(list(a=1),list(a=2),list(a=3))
b.vals <- 11:13
mylist <- lapply(
  1:length(mylist), 
  function(x) {
    mylist[[x]]$b <- b.vals[[x]]
    mylist[[x]]
} )
```

Comment: yep, this is what I came up with too, except for I use `c(b=b.vals[x],mylist[[x]])` instead of `<-`.  thanks!

Comment: @sds, your approach is a bit cleaner.